# Why Javascript $(document.body) does not load outside of the source file?

Tags: javascript, razor

First of, a quick word about my setup.

I have a global JS file *common.js*, where I store all commonly used functions. This file is bundled and set to load along with _Layout.cshtml view file.

Along with that, I have a view file, which generates an html object like following:

```
<a class="printreport" href="#" data-reporttype="8" data-certid="1111">Print</a>
```

Mentioned view file loads javascript source file through extended method

```
@section scripts {
    @Html.LoadVersionedJavascriptFile("~/location/sourcefile.js")
}
```

In order to optimize my code, I decided to write a snippet function, which will make every html object with "printreport" class run it

Inside source file:

```
$(function(){
    //other stuff

    //Every html object that has printreport as a class will run this function
    $(document.body).on('click', '.printreport', function () {

    //get reporttype data from object
    var reportType = $(this).data('reporttype');
    var link = $("#RootDirectory").val();

    switch (reportType) {
        //other cases
        case 8:     //Certification
            var certId = $(this).data('certid');        //Get certid data from object
            link += '/Reports/ReportPopUp.aspx?report=' + reportType + '&CertId=' + certId;
            break;
        }   
    //code
    });
});
```

Inside the source file, it responds and works as intended. However, if I try moving that snippet from the source.js into a global common.js (I confirmed that file is loaded during execution), it simply does not respond, and clicking on link does nothing:

Inside common.js file:

```
//declaration of global variables

$(document).ready(function () {

}

$(document.body).on('click', '.printreport', function () {
    //code
}
```

Structure of common.js file is as above, it is not encapsulated into anything.

My question is: **Am I loading document.body part improperly? What could be the possible cause of such unresponsiveness?**

Comment: Have you tried moving the event listener inside the document ready function?

Comment: @AndrésAndrade I considered it as a possible potion. You mean like moving the whole document.body inside document.ready section?

Comment: Exactly. BTW, attaching delegated event handlers near the top of the document tree can degrade performance (document.body in this case) since each time the event occurs jQuery must compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every element in the path from the event target up to the top of the document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location as close as possible to the target elements. (http://api.jquery.com/on)

Comment: @AndrésAndrade Currently trying it out...

Comment: @AndrésAndrade Yes, it seems to be the cause of my problem. I will accept your suggestion as an answer. However, can you please also add why my initial way of doing it was wrong? I looked at the document.ready part and assumed that document.body should be loaded the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your click handler inside `$(document).ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document.body).on('click', '.printreport', function () {
        //code
    }
}
```

`$(document).ready` is an event which fires up when document is ready and since your html is interpreted from top to bottom, your elements could not be present when your jQuery code runs (`$(document.body)`).